# Find all solutions of $Ax = 0$ in parametric vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find all solutions of $Ax = 0$ in parametric vector form where A is row equivalent to the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}
-1&-4&0&-4\\2&-8&0&8
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: That it would be similar to the first row  except for 4 instead of -4

Comment: Not just 4.....the whole row is -(first row).

Comment: it would be (1 -4 0 4)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do first is put your matrix A into RREF (reduced row echelon form). The reduced form of your matrix A is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&4\\0&1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$
   $\\$ So what can we do from here? We can write the general equation, which provides us with a parametric description of the solution set: $\\$

$x_{1}$ = -4$x_{4}$ $\\$

$x_{2}$ = 0 $\\$

$x_{3}$,$x_{4}$ are free $\\$

Now we can write our solution in parametric vector form: $\\$

$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4}
\end{pmatrix}$ $ =
\begin{pmatrix}
-4x_{4}\\0\\x_{3}\\x_{4}
\end{pmatrix}$ $ = x_{3}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}$ $ + x_{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
-4\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

I think what your asking is to find the null space.

So follow these steps-

put your matrix to reduced row echleon form and then find the basis.

The span of the basis is the null space (all the solutions to Ax= 0)

Since you want to give it in a parametric vector form, it is the same thing as any linear combinations of the basis vector that you find.